# FileUploader Asp mvc Telerik Asynchrounous Content

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, telerik-mvc

I tried to Use the Telerik component Upload in asp mvc .

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Upload()
            .Name("attachement")
    .Multiple(true)
    .Async(async => async
        .Save("Save", "Image")
        .Remove("Remove", "Image")
        .AutoUpload(true)
        ).ClientEvents(events => events.OnSuccess("onSuccess")))
```

In My Controller I have:

```
 public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase attachement)
    {
        var fileName = attachement.FileName;
        Guid id = SaveImage(attachement);

        return Json(
            new
            {
                Succces = true,
                Content=id,
            }

            );
    }
```

In my View I need to display the content of the Json Result ,
I have a event on the uploader called OnSucces

```
   function onSuccess(e) {


}
```

How Can I get the JsonContent in this method javascript and display the content .
Or all this logic is wrong .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [sending and receiving metadata](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-upload-sending-and-receiving-metadata.html#Receiving) help article.